# How do I get sound working in Unreal Tournament 2004?

Tags: alsa

I'm playing UT2004 FOR linux but if I run it with  plain

```
./ut2004
```

I've no sound in it, if I run it with

```
aoss ./ut2004
```

using in such way the ALSA-Oss library, the game often crash - I suppose - with

```
WARNING: ALC_EXT_capture is subject to change!
```

I noticed the game 'require' the openAL libs.. So what package I should install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the Pulseausio OSS Wrapper [padsp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/padsp.1.html) :

```
padsp ./ut2004
```

Comment: with this wrapper works well :)

Answer (score 4):

If you were to try and play this game with audio in 15.04 you would need to actually symlink for the current **libopenal.so.1.15.1** file to the **ut2004/System** directory replacing the default **openal.so** file that resides there.

Essentially running something similar to the following:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1.15.1 /home/itnet7/ut2004/System/openal.so
```

(Please make sure you adjust the path to reflect your installation, and username)

Once I created the symlink, I was able to launch UT2004 normally (without using aoss or padsp) and sound worked.

To install the game, I used my backup from many years ago, extracting the main UT2004 installation directory to my user account's home directory and upon launching it ran into some of the issues with libstdc++5 and libSDL mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games/Native/UnrealTournament2004). I discovered that link after getting I was able to get the game running, and it helped me fix the sound. I'm posting it here in case it helps save someone else some time that might be looking for it as well.

[image: Sreenshot of UT2004 running natively on Ubuntu 15.04 with Sound]

Comment: Just a small comment: don't forget to use `/usr/lib32` or similar instead of `/usr/lib` for some Linux distros, for example, my ArchLinux ;) Just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out why it doesn't work, and it was 64-bit OpenAL that I mistakingly put into `System` folder. Replaced with 32-bit - and there it goes! Works like a charm :)

Comment: For anyone else like me who needed more details: in [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=888950&page=2&p=12099861#post12099861) it's described your same procedure, but with more details as how to locate the files to replace.